# Creating Case via PHPToolkit fails to activate email queue

Tags: email, php

I've successfully setup a case system that models the Web to Case system, because I couldn't use it specifically because it lacked in the feature department.

So, I wrote a function that processes all of the data I need, but I'm having trouble actually activating the typical the email I received from Web-to-Case after a case is created:

> **Case Successfully Created in Salesforce**
>
> A new case with id 500d000000hB4nL has been successfully created.
>
> To view the new case, go to <<URL>>

Here is the function I created based off the PHPToolkit 20.0:

```
function create_new_case($case){
    try {
        //Open our connection
        $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
        $mySforceConnection->createConnection('soapclient/my.wsdl.xml');
        $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD . SECURITY_TOKEN);

        //Set assignment rules so the proper team is assigned
        $header = new AssignmentRuleHeader('01Qd0000000D4cw', false);
        $mySforceConnection->setAssignmentRuleHeader($header);
        $sObject = new stdClass();

        //Client Related
        $sObject->AccountId             =$case['AccountId'];
        $sObject->ContactId             =$case['contactId'];
        $sObject->Type                  =$case['type'];
        $sObject->Reason                =$case['reason'];
        $sObject->Origin                =$case['origin'];
        $sObject->Subject               =$case['subject'];
        $sObject->Description           =$case['description'];
        $sObject->Priority              =$case['priority'];

        //Staff related
        $sObject->Case_Owner_Email__c   =$case['email'];
        $sObject->Case_Opened_By__c     =$case['ownerId'];

        //Confirm website URL exists before appending to case
        if(strlen($case['website'])>5) {
            $sObject->Website__c        =$case['website'];
        }

        //Create the case in the Case object
        $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject), 'Case');

        return TRUE;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR: ";
        echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
        echo $e->faultstring;
    }
}
```

Yes, it does create the case successfully. I posted full code incase anyone needs any guidance creating a case via PHP in the future.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the [EmailHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_emailheader.htm) in order to trigger emails (it defaults to false). This will cause the system to send out any notifications it would normally.

Comment: I don't know how I missed the EmailHeader. I did add it as you've suggested, and even set all of the fields to true: `$header = new AssignmentRuleHeader('01Qd0000000D4cw', false);
            $emailHeader = new emailHeader(true, true, true);
            $mySforceConnection->setEmailHeader($emailHeader);
            $mySforceConnection->setAssignmentRuleHeader($header);` But I've yet to receive an email, neither as the case owner or web contact. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ITAdminNC You can get debug logs by logging in as the user you are running that code as and opening the developer console. It should tell you if the emails are being sent/triggered.

Comment: You've definitely set in me down the right path. I realized that the email I was receiving was only a debug email originally from the web to case. I've setup a workflow, team and defined roles, and made myself a member of that role. The only issue now is that when I select "Case Team: Technical Support" as the recipient in the email alert, it doesn't send to me; but if I choose "User: <me>" it sends immediately to my email. I've double checked and made sure I'm a member of the predefined case team, and I am. Would really prefer to use those instead of selecting users here.

Comment: BTW- I went and gave you a vote on a couple of your posts in IdeaExchange at Salesforce as an extra thanks for the help here today! :)

Comment: @ITAdminNC Those votes don't help me, but they do help *us*. Do make sure you get out and vote! Also, you might want to go with assignment rules/queues/etc as opposed to using case teams, at least for case creation. It's the best way to get a notification to whomever ends up with the case (or even all members of a queue, if you set it up that way). I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: For sure! I added the latest log I have to the main question. I have the workflow setup now to update the field to Technical Support queue, and I've got myself listed in that group with "Sent email alerts" checked as well for the entire queue.. But still can't receive an email. It's really mind boggling.

Comment: I've got most of it figured out now. Afterwards, I had an issue with notifying the custom field email of new comments, so I created a custom datetype field (comments__c) on the case object, and whenever a new comment was posted, I would update that field. Then I'd have another action waiting to detect changes to that field, and on change it will send an email to the field I needed that I couldn't access from the case comment object.